# how to make selected item as readonly i.e. it can't be change dropdown in struts 1

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, struts

How to make selected item as readonly i.e. it can't be change by clicking on dropdown in sturts 1.3

I have to fix the selected item in dropdown that user cant't change it when they try to edit the option to select other option.

```
             <html:select property="stdUnitId" styleId="stdUnitId" style="width:153px;" styleClass="required"  >

                            <c:forEach var="record" items="${unitList}">
                                <c:choose>
                                    <c:when test="${record.id == SUID}">
                                        <option value="${record.id}" selected="selected">
                                            ${record.code}
                                        </option>
                                    </c:when>
                                    <c:otherwise>
                                        <option value="${record.id}">
                                            ${record.code}
                                        </option>
                                    </c:otherwise>
                                </c:choose>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </html:select>
                <%} else {%>
                    <select name="stdUnitId" id="stdUnitId" style="width:153px;" class="required" disabled="disabled">
                            <option value="">--SELECT--</option>
                                <c:forEach var="record" items="${unitList}">
                                    <option value="${record.id}">${record.code }</option>
                                </c:forEach>
                        </select>
                <%} } %>
                </td>                   
            </tr>
```

Comment: Have you tried disabled="true" in select tag???

Comment: disabled="true" working & thank for your answer.